# jquery setting value to null option of select

Tags: jquery

how to setting default value for empty or null value of option:

HTML:

```
<select name="master_id" id='master_id' >
    <option value="">  -   -   -   </option>
```

or

```
<select name="master_id" id='master_id' >
    <option>  -   -   -   </option>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/cL5NH/)

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? Perhaps we have a better suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

i found it:

```
<select name="master_id" id='master_id' >
    <option>  -   -   -   </option>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#test option:not([value])').prop('selected', true)
```